# PHP Declarator In If-Statement Scope

Tags: php, scope, language-construct

This is pretty basic.
Let's say you define a variable in an if statement

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Can I access $stmt below the if statement?
Or does $stmt need to be defined above the if?

Comment: Why don't you try it? But yes, $stmt will be defined by the `if` and remain defined for the rest of the function.

Comment: @Marc B I tried, but the $stmt->error was not logging anything to my text file so I was suspicious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not have block level scope, only function level scope. `$stmt` will be available anywhere below that if statement (in and out of the `if`).

Something to keep in mind however, if you define new variables inside the `if` block, will only exist if that `if` evaluates to `true`.

Eg:

```
<?php
$var1 = true;
if ($var2 = false) { 
    $var3 = true; // this does not get executed
} else {
    $var4 = 5;
}
var_dump($var1); // true
var_dump($var2); // false
var_dump($var3); // ERROR - undefined variable $var3
var_dump($var4); // 5
```

Comment: So you can declare within the if-block and the variable will exist below the if? Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic test:

```
if ($stmt = 5) {
    var_dump($stmt);
}

var_dump($stmt);
```

Outputs:

```
int(5)
int(5)
```

Yes, You can "access $stmt below the if statement".